# Sending Notification to users from a Facebook Application

Tags: php, facebook, notifications

I need to send a notification to specific users of my app on facebook. And by notification i mean the red number that appears on the globe on the top, not the one that appears beside the app in the sidebar. 
Is it possible to send such notifications from my app? If yes, how?
I have used the PHP SDK.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of August 31st 2012 you can send your users notifications:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app_notifications/

Answer (score 1):

The only way to send a notification that lights up the globe icon is via a user-to-user request: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/

That can only be used by canvas apps, and also requires popping up a dialog where the user picks the recipients to send the request to.

Comment: Thats sad. Any idea as to why they dont allow apps to send notificatios?

Comment: Because shady developer types would most likely use that to spam people to no end …